# Appium Android How to tap using the TEXT value

Tags: java, android, appium

I want to play a song by making Appium tap the song name. Is there a code which can allow me to tap any element by using the TEXT field? I cannot use the resource id field here as there will be multiple songs later on. I tried using `By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text='"+song name+"']");` but that did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to write the following code in my test:

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR2);
```

Now I can use the TEXT value by writing that song name in the XPath like this:

```
By.xpath("//*[@text='" + element + "']");
```

Here element is the text value shown in UIAutomatiorViewer.

Comment: this works. Thank you. where was this cap documented?

Answer (score 5):

You have got the class name wrong in the xpath.

It should be the following based on what I see on uiautomatorviewer

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+songname+"']");
```

Comment: Yeah that was a typo but unfortunately the solution you wrote is the same I have tried in the code & it did not work.

Comment: This is the correct way to find it.  What is returned when you attempt to to run with this? 

It's possible there could be a view layering issue that doesn't allow you to tap where the element is on the z-axis. I've seen this before and it's usually fixed by having my developers clean up a broken view model.

What happens when you try tapping the area in which that element is (you can make up coordinates inside the bounds)?

Answer (score 2):

```
There is no need to using custom xpath for this.
First you have to take all the elements with that resource ID and click on required element if it contains the text on which you want to click.
You can use the below code.

    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("resource-id"));
    For(WebElement element:elements)
    {
        if(element.getText().equals("textProperty"))
        {
            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In xPath 2 if you use Appium inspector with python you can use

```
//*[contains(@text, 'Song Name')]
```

that will only search for the text that contains the song name and it doesn't have to be exact same value.
example :

```
els1 = driver.find_elements(by=AppiumBy.XPATH, value="//*[contains(@text, 'Song Name' )]")
```

if you want to use for the exact text value you can use

```
//*[@text= 'Song Name']"
```

Answer (score 0):

If @bsk answer is not working. It might be because of a new line break...

Could you try this to verify?

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, 'Ishq De Fanniyar (Female)')]");
```

Also is not a bad practice to use @resource-id too...

```
By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='com.xefyr.ridez:id/tv_song_title' and contains(@text, 'Ishq De Fanniyar (Female)')]");
```

Comment: Your first solution did not work. Unfortunately I cant use resource id here because there are going to be multiple songs later on & every one of them will have the same resource id. I am trying to write a framework & so I have to make it as much generic & simple for a non programmer as possible. All he/she needs to do is mention the name of the song according to the text value as shown in the UIAutomator. I dont understand why this is not working in Appium.

Comment: 1st. The second solution will work even faster even with every song having same ID... As you can see is a @resource-id='' **AND** @text=''. 2nd. Can you try changing //android.widget.TextView for //* and if you have no luck... Maybe this (small piece of text)? By.xpath("//*[contains(@text, 'Ishq')]");

Comment: Btw... Your screenshot is from AndroidAutomationViewer.bat. Why don't you try to inspect from appium itself? What is your Appium version? I suggest you to update to the last version of appium-desktop

Comment: Still not working. Appium keeps on searching at the FindElement method  for infinite duration even though I am using only explicit wait. with both of your suggestions. I also tried searching via UIAutomator technique by using `MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.xefyr.ridez:id/tv_song_title\").textContains(\"Ishq\");");`. In the debug window I can see **[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CONTAINS_TEXT=Ishq, RESOURCE_ID=com.xefyr.ridez:id/tv_song_title]** but still it fails with no element found message.

Comment: And what about using appium-desktop?

Comment: I do not see any feature in Appium Desktop 1.3.1 which can allow me to inspect. I am on Windows 10. Am I missing something?

Comment: Appium Desktop 1.3.1 is an old version... Can you update to newer versions? Maybe > 1.7

Comment: 1.3.1 is the version of the GUI. Otherwise Appium version that is shipped in is 1.7.2